# VBA Excel - FileCopy - Wrong Format

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i = 1 To cantfilas Step 1
Worksheets("Tool").Activate
nombretemporal = Cells(j + 1, "H").Value
fso.CopyFile Cells(j + 1, "G"), folder & "\" & nombretemporal
Cells(j + 1, "J").Value = "Done"
j = j + 1
Next i
```

The macro is longer, however. It picks the name for each file from a spreadsheet (all of them are like *nameoffileYYYY-MM-DD.xls*, although most of them come in zip format. I need to copy them to another location and give them the right name (i.e, with today's date *nameoffile2014-05-16*)

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem ?  There is no question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a leap of faith here:

When you're appending the date to `nombretemporal`, you are adding it using something like `nombretemporal = fileName & Date`

Instead of this, try specifying the format of the date like this:

`nombretemporal = fileName & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")`